# Feature selection by lasso in two samples compared to one joint sample

Tags: regression, feature-selection, lasso, asymptotics

Let's say you have two sets of features $X_1$ and $X_2$ together with a response variable $Y$. I wonder whether the two following procedures are identical asymptotically (or in finite samples) in terms of the features selected:

$\mathbf{Procedure}$ 1: Run two separate lasso regressions, i.e. $Y$ on $X_1$ and $Y$ on $X_2$. Pick non-zero features and denote them $\tilde{X}_1$ and $\tilde{X}_2$. Denote the union $Z_1=\tilde{X}_1 \cup \tilde{X}_2$.

$\mathbf{Procedure}$ 2: Run one lasso regression on the union, i.e. $Y$ on $X_1 \cup X_2$. Pick non-zero features and denote them $Z_2$.

QUESTION: Does $Z_1$ contain the same features as $Z_2$? I.e. $Z_1=Z_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe they would. Let's say you have two highly correlated features that are important for prediction. Having them in $X_1$ could result in choice of only one (not guaranteed of course), but having one of them in $X_1$, and the other in $X_2$ could result in choosing the both. So, $Z_1$ would have both of them, while $Z_2$ might have only one of them.

Comment: That is a good point! Do you know whether any of the lasso extensions might improve this, e.g. elastic net? Under assumptions of no correlation things would be better of course, but that's not realistic in my case.